# AngularJS ng-repeat json-format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I ng-repeat this kind of json data? I want to echo game and stats separataly.

```
{
"game": [
 {
 "home": "Home Team",
 "away": "Away Team",
 "date": "2015-01-13",
 "result": "2-0"
 }
 ],
 "stats": [
 {
 "event": "Goal",
 "time": 27,
 "player": "Player One"
 },
 {
 "event": "Yellow Card",
 "time": 52,
 "player": "Player Two",
 }
 ]
 }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to feed ng-repeat the data inside each object. Let's say that the JSON you posted is stored in $scope.data. To get show the game information, just give ng-repeat the game array like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="g in data.game">
Home: {{g.home}}<br>
Away: {{g.away}}<br>
Date: {{g.date}}<br>
Result: {{g.result}}
</div>
```

Do the same thing with stats and you display the information from each array.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried it like this but it didn't work. But now, after 3 hours of playing around I realised that the problem is that those brackets are conflicting with laravel blade.. I feel so stupid now :D But anyway, this is the right answer :)